# Retaining clipboard content during code execution

Tags: excel, clipboard, vba

This seems like it should be a simple problem but I've been unable to solve it. I have a program I'm writing where the user is babied through these steps:

**Step 1:** Go to another spreadsheet and copy the content
**Step 2:** Come back to my spreadsheet and press a button to paste that content

When they press my button it needs to unlock the current sheet and paste the data without any of the formatting. This is what I have:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                       Operation:=xlNone, _
                       SkipBlanks:=False, _
                       Transpose:=False
```

So it works perfectly if I don't do the "Unprotect" line, but I'm trying to stop people from pasting the data without using my button.

I know that the issue is something to do with clipboard content being lost when I unprotect the sheet but the methods I've used to retain that content aren't working, namely:

- Lib User32 - OpenClipboard and CloseClipboard
- DataObject - GetFromClipboard, PutInClipboard

Curiously, it works perfectly if I debug the VBA and step through line by line?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I've solved it (but someone may have a better solution). I believe the problem was that when I used the DataObject method of keeping the clipboard contents it stripped the formatting and so it couldn't PasteSpecial, that's actually fine with me because I'm only after the data anyway! With that in mind, this seems to work:

```
Dim dClipBoard As MsForms.DataObject
Dim sClipBoard As String
Set dClipBoard = New MsForms.DataObject
dClipBoard.GetFromClipboard
sClipBoard = dClipBoard.GetText
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Set dClipBoard = New MsForms.DataObject
dClipBoard.SetText sClipBoard
dClipBoard.PutInClipboard
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: +1 very cool use of the `MsForms.DataObject`, which I was totally unaware of until I needed it just now. Great work here!

Comment: If you run into a problem with this where the "dClipBoard.PutInClipboard" is adding two characters instead of whatever the sClipBoard text is, it's likely due to have file explorer open. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134654/vba-settext-and-putinclipboard-putting-two-symbols-in-clipboard-instead-of-des) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly address your issue, but... why not avoid copy and paste?

If you are only pasting the values, then you don't need to copy. When you do step 1. "Go to another spreadsheet and copy the content" instead of copying, you can store the values into an array. When you want to "paste" the values, just place the array back into the `ActiveSheet`.

Now that I've said that, here's example code:

```
Private myArray
Sub fakecopy()
    myArray = Selection
End Sub
Sub FakePaste()
    With ActiveSheet
        If IsArray(myArray) Then
            .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(myArray), UBound(myArray, 2))) = myArray
        Else
            .Cells(1, 1) = myArray
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

When you want to paste the values, just set the appropriate range to equal the array.

Additionally, if when you protect the sheet you set `UserInterfaceOnly = true`, then there is no need to unprotect it to run your code.

Comment: The problem is that the user has to retrieve the data for my program to continue, I can't get it for them. I couldn't think of an easier way than for them to simply open the new spreadsheet they've created for me and then "Ctrl-A", "Ctrl-C"...anything more complicated than that and I don't think they'll cope :-) But thanks for your input, I might look into the "UserInterfaceOnly" option you mention.

Comment: Ah. When you said you were babying them through the steps, I assumed that you were helping them copy as well. I suppose that's a little excessive? hehe